# GCC compiles leading zero count poorly unless Haswell specified

Tags: c, performance, gcc, x86, intel

GCC supports the [`__builtin_clz(int x)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fclz-4249) builtin, which counts the number of number of *leading zeros* (consecutive most-significant zeros) in the argument.

Among other things<sup>0</sup>, this is great for efficiently implementing the `lg(unsigned int x)` function, which takes the base-2 logarithm of `x`, rounding down<sup>1</sup>:

```
/** return the base-2 log of x, where x > 0 */
unsigned lg(unsigned x) {
  return 31U - (unsigned)__builtin_clz(x);
}
```

This works in the straightforward way - in particular consider the case `x == 1` and `clz(x) == 31` - then `x == 2^0` so `lg(x) == 0` and `31 - 31 == 0` and we get the correct result. Higher values of `x` work similarly.

Assuming the builtin is efficiently implemented, this ends much better than the alternate [pure C solutions](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious).

Now as it happens, the *count leading zeros* operation is essentially the dual of the [`bsr`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html) instruction in x86. That returns the index of the most-significant 1-bit<sup>2</sup> in the argument. So if there are 10 leading zeros, the first 1-bit is in bit 21 of the argument. In general we have `31 - clz(x) == bsr(x)` and in so `bsr` in fact *directly* implements our desired `lg()` function, without the superfluous `31U - ...` part.

In fact, you can read between the line and see that the `__builtin_clz` function was implemented with `bsr` in mind: it is defined as *undefined behavior* if the argument is zero, when of course the "leading zeros" operation is perfectly well-defined as 32 (or whatever the bit-size of `int` is) with a zero argument. So `__builtin_clz` was certainly implemented with the idea of being efficiently mapped to a `bsr` instruction on x86.

However, looking at what GCC actually does, at `-O3` with otherwise default options: it [adds a ton of extra junk](https://godbolt.org/g/gvYBrH):

```
lg(unsigned int):
        bsr     edi, edi
        mov     eax, 31
        xor     edi, 31
        sub     eax, edi
        ret
```

The `xor edi,31` line is effectively a `not edi` for the bottom 4 bits that actually matter, that's off-by-one<sup>3</sup> from `neg edi` which turns the result of `bsr` into `clz`. Then the `31 - clz(x)` is carried out.

However with `-mtune=haswell`, the [code simplifies](https://godbolt.org/g/gvYBrH) into exactly the expected single `bsr` instruction:

```
lg(unsigned int):
        bsr     eax, edi
        ret
```

Why that is the case is very unclear to me. The `bsr` instruction has been around for a couple decades before Haswell, and the behavior is, AFAIK, unchanged. It's not just an issue of *tuning* for a particular arch, since `bsr` + a bunch of extra instructions isn't going to be faster than a plain `bsr` and furthermore using `-mtune=haswell` [still results](https://godbolt.org/g/5bDhWQ) in the slower code.

The situation for **64-bit** inputs and outputs is [even slightly worse](https://godbolt.org/g/5t7867): there is an extra `movsx` in the critical path which seems to do nothing since the result from `clz` will never be negative. Again, the `-march=haswell` variant is optimal with a single `bsr` instruction.

Finally, let's check the big players in the non-Windows compiler space, [`icc` and `clang`](https://godbolt.org/g/WIROzq). `icc` just does a bad job and adds redundant stuff like `neg eax; add eax, 31; neg  eax; add eax, 31;` - wtf? `clang` does a good job regardless of `-march`.

---

<sup>0</sup> Such as scanning a *bitmap* for the first set bit.

<sup>1</sup> The logarithm of 0 is undefinited, and so calling our function with a 0 argument is *undefined behavior*.

<sup>2</sup> Here, the LSB is the 0th bit and the MSB is the 31st.

<sup>3</sup> Recall that `-x == ~x + 1` in twos-complement.

Comment: So many problems with GCC, I see (and do) complaints about it everywhere. Slowly even MSVC gets better than it, haha.

Comment: Well to be fair it generates some really nice code in some cases, better than the competition, but then it kind of drops the ball in other cases. I have a feeling that there is a lot of money being poured into LLVM and hence `clang` is slowly eclipsing the other options.

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a known issue with gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50168

Comment: Good catch, but it looks like a distinct issue. It's mostly about the extra sign-extension stuff when you are using the 64-bit `_builtin_clzl(long)`, which returns a 32-bit value. I also noticed that behavior, but you can get around it by casting the return value to unsigned - and in any case none of this applies to my example which is only 32-bit (using `__builting_clz(int)`). So it's a separate issue.