# How to get GCC to optimize long XOR chain

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

I have a loop like:

```
uint32_t result = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < CONSTANT; ++i )
{
    result ^= expr;
}
return result;
```

Overall, GCC is doing a beautiful job with this code.  It fully unrolls the loop and generates optimal code for `expr`.  However, it does the `result` XOR `CONSTANT` times.  It could be accumulating partial results and XOR'ing them together hierarchically.

I suspect if I hand-unroll this with macros I can do it manually (`CONSTANT` isn't large), but I'm wondering why it doesn't see this, or if I'm doing something that's preventing it due to some arcane C++ language rule.

Comment: What does `expr` look like?

Comment: What exactly  is expr?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here, but doesn't "XOR'ing them together hierarchically" still require the same total number of XOR operations?

Comment: "*It could be accumulating partial results and XOR'ing them together hierarchically.*" Why do you think that would be better? And whatever the reason, how do you think the compiler could know it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It breaks the dependency chain. Most processors today can run 3 or 4 `XOR` instructions per cycle. But you can't utilize that throughput unless you break the dependency chain to make them parallelizable (at the instruction level).

Comment: @Mysticial That might or might not matter, depending on what dependency chain `expr` has, which we can't tell.

Comment: @Ben What's `expr`? Is it a variable? Or something that changes with each iteration? Side-effects? If it's just a variable, the "correct" optimization is to either no-op or XOR once depending on the parity of `CONSTANT`.

Comment: `expr` is trivial.  It's 2 instructions once compiled.

Comment: @BenJackson - why don't you just post the code with `expr` defined? It makes a huge difference, for e.g., if `expr` depends on `i`, depends on globals, etc, etc.

Comment: Try `-march=atom` and read the comment before ix86_reassociation_width in gcc/config/i386/i386.c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is likely no benefit to accumulating partial results here. If you use a divide and conquer strategy (XOR evens with odds to halve size, then repeat, halving number of operands each time), you still end up doing `O(CONSTANT)` work (one half the work plus one quarter the work plus one eighth the work, etc., eventually performing `CONSTANT - 1` operations).

Accumulating partial results in chunks behaves the same. Fundamentally, you must have `CONSTANT - 1` XOR operations. And since these are fixed width registers, not growing arbitrary precision integers, the work for each XOR is identical. You're highly unlikely to realize any gains at all from a more complicated approach barring parallelizing the `expr` work.

Comment: The OP's original code has a dependency chain of `XOR`s. Each can't execute until the previous one finishes. Most processors today can run 3 or 4 `XOR` instructions/cycle - but only if they are independent. So while the amount of work is still the same, you gain in ILP.

Comment: @Mysticial: Except the OP's work include an unspecified expression that is being calculated prior to being XOR-ed in. Assuming it's not completely trivial, the work required to compute `expr` would likely interfere with the ideal 3-4 `XOR` per clock. The `expr` instructions would either be similarly simple (add, sub) and therefore be keeping stuff occupied anyway, or more expensive and therefore acting as a bottleneck that renders the `XOR` work "free" (that is, the previous "loop"'s `XOR` is resolving well before the next `expr` is finished, so the dependency chain isn't an issue).

Comment: Under specific circumstances, it's possible you could optimize this by divide and conquer, but it would likely involve temporary storage to achieve it (compute several `expr`s, `XOR` them together, compute more, `XOR` them together, etc.). If that causes intermediates to spill from registers to the stack though, it's unlikely to be a worthwhile tradeoff.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I am used to thinking about SIMD where I would be getting parallelism by breaking it into subproblems.  But there's no SIMD here, so your analysis is correct.

Comment: ShadowRanger - at least to an extent the "temporary storage" is likely to be free, in the form of registers. Sure, they are limited, but you don't need to fully "treeify" the xor chain anyway - just enough to make use of the ILP offered by the target architecture. Anyway, discussing the specifics is very tough because @BenJackson has for some reason refused to clarify the nature of `expr`, so we can't actually analyze the actual behavior.

Answer (score 1):

For your loop, either `expr` doesn't depend on `i`, in which case `gcc` should optimize away the loop entirely<sup>1</sup>, or it does in which case `gcc` could *still* optimize it away (since the loop bounds are constant, the whole loop can be pre-calculated).

It seems like it [fails in the latter case](https://godbolt.org/g/XZqaaW) though, _unless you [optimize for](https://godbolt.org/g/aXJu3E) `-march=haswell`. That seems really weird, but I've seen exactly that kind of [behavior before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40456481/149138).

In any case<sup>2</sup>, you mentioned that `expr` compiles to two instructions. Adding 3 instructions for the `xor`, the loop increment, and test instruction, you are already at five instructions for this loop, which exceeds the retire rate of even high-end x86 CPUs, so there is no benefit to seeking out additional instruction level parallelism here (unless perhaps you are compiling to a non-x86 arch with even higher width?).

---

<sup>1</sup> ... and it general it does, at `-O3` anyway.

<sup>2</sup> We just have to guess here since you are really guarding the secrets of `expr` tightly.

Comment: My question had all of the necessary information to get a correct answer (which I have already marked), which in this case was that my fuzzy thinking on how to best compute a long chain of XORs was incorrect.  So in that sense, Stackoverflow was useful to me, if unnecessarily hostile.  I guess the intention is to encourage me to delete my question, so that no one else can benefit from it.  BTW, this is not on x86.

Comment: @BenJackson - of course it doesn't have the necessary information. I think you are actually right that `gcc` should use the associativity of `xor` to make the calculation more parallel, but it depends on the nature of `expr` and on the width of the architecture (in particular, the width in `gcc`'s machine mode). Knowing that `expr` is a couple of instructions isn't enough. x86 doesn't really matter here, I was just using it as example of a high-end architecture with a reasonable width. Some archs do have higher widths (PPC, Cyclone) - but the devil is in the details.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I'd much rather see the quesiton updated with details of `expr` than deleted! Then someone could give an even better answer that would help others.

Comment: ... and the thrust of my answer is "not only should gcc possibly optimize the way it groups the `xor`, but it should in principle be able to eliminate the loop entirely, unless `expr` is quite unusual".

Answer (score 0):

In a strict XOR calculation there technically would never be more than two values fed in to the XOR calculation, as it would not logically make sense, and would only tell us the combined parity of all of the numbers if we exceed two values being XOR'd in a chain like var1 ^ var2 ^ var3, and so technically by using more than two you should only be able to tell it's parity, whether the result is even or odd.

In most programming languages however the compiler automatically creates a cascading series of XOR operations that process only two of the values at a time, and then take that result and XOR it with the next until it has processed them all, so really there can be no such thing as an actual batched XOR chain or list as an expression, although we can write them in that manner and the compiler handles the details.