# Efficiently dividing unsigned value by a power of two, rounding up - in CUDA

Tags: optimization, cuda, rounding, gpgpu, integer-division

I was just reading:

[Efficiently dividing unsigned value by a power of two, rounding up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431599/efficiently-dividing-unsigned-value-by-a-power-of-two-rounding-up)

and I was wondering what was the fastest way to do this in CUDA. Of course by "fast" I mean in terms of throughput (that question also addressed the case of subsequent calls depending on each other).

For the `lg()` function mentioned in that question (base-2 logarithm of divisor), suppose we have:

```
template <typename T> __device__ int find_first_set(T x);
template <> __device__ int find_first_set<uint32_t>(uint32_t x) { return __ffs(x);   }
template <> __device__ int find_first_set<uint64_t>(uint64_t x) { return __ffsll(x); }

template <typename T> __device__ int lg(T x) { return find_first_set(x) - 1; }
```

---

**Edit:** Since I've been made aware that there's no find-first-sert in PTX, nor in the instruction set of all nVIDIA GPUs up to this time, let's replace that `lg()` with the following:

```
template <typename T> __df__ int population_count(T x);
template <> int population_count<uint32_t>(uint32_t x) { return __popc(x);   }
template <> int population_count<uint64_t>(uint64_t x) { return __popcll(x); }

template <typename T>
__device__ int lg_for_power_of_2(T x) { return population_count(x - 1); }
```

---

and we now need to implement

```
template <typename T> T div_by_power_of_2_rounding_up(T p, T q);
```

... for `T = uint32_t` and `T = uint64_t`. (`p` is the dividend, `q` is the divisor).

**Notes:**

- As in the original question, we may *not* assume that `p <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - q` or that `p > 0` - that would collapse the various interesting alternatives :-)
- 0 is not a power of 2, so we may assume `q != 0`.
- I realize solutions might differ for 32-bit and 64-bit; I'm more interested in the former but also in the latter.
- Let's focus on Maxwell and Pascal chips.

Comment: Is an extra pre-condition allowed? It can be written `(dividend + mask) >> log_2_of_divisor` *if* that doesn't cause wrapping

Comment: @harold: No; like in the original question, that's not allowed, see edit.

Answer (score 3):

With funnel shifting available, a possible 32 bit strategy is doing a 33bit shift (essentially) preserving the carry of the addition so it be done before the shift, such as this: (not tested)

```
unsigned sum = dividend + mask;
unsigned result = __funnelshift_r(sum, sum < mask, log_2_of_divisor);
```

**Edit by @einpoklum**:

Tested using @RobertCrovella's program, seems to work fine. The test kernel PTX for SM_61 is:

```
    .reg .pred      %p<2>;
    .reg .b32       %r<12>;


    ld.param.u32    %r5, [_Z4testjj_param_0];
    ld.param.u32    %r6, [_Z4testjj_param_1];
    neg.s32         %r7, %r6;
    and.b32         %r8, %r6, %r7;
    clz.b32         %r9, %r8;
    mov.u32         %r10, 31;
    sub.s32         %r4, %r10, %r9;
    add.s32         %r11, %r6, -1;
    add.s32         %r2, %r11, %r5;
    setp.lt.u32     %p1, %r2, %r11;
    selp.u32        %r3, 1, 0, %p1;
    // inline asm
    shf.r.wrap.b32 %r1, %r2, %r3, %r4;
    // inline asm
    st.global.u32   [r], %r1;
    ret;
```

and the SASS is:

```
/*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];                 /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
/*0010*/                   MOV R0, c[0x0][0x144];                /* 0x4c98078005170000 */
/*0018*/                   IADD R2, RZ, -c[0x0][0x144];          /* 0x4c1100000517ff02 */
                                                                 /* 0x001c4c00fe4007f1 */
/*0028*/                   IADD32I R0, R0, -0x1;                 /* 0x1c0ffffffff70000 */
/*0030*/                   LOP.AND R2, R2, c[0x0][0x144];        /* 0x4c47000005170202 */
/*0038*/                   FLO.U32 R2, R2;                       /* 0x5c30000000270002 */
                                                                 /* 0x003fd800fe2007e6 */
/*0048*/                   IADD R5, R0, c[0x0][0x140];           /* 0x4c10000005070005 */
/*0050*/                   ISETP.LT.U32.AND P0, PT, R5, R0, PT;  /* 0x5b62038000070507 */
/*0058*/                   IADD32I R0, -R2, 0x1f;                /* 0x1d00000001f70200 */
                                                                 /* 0x001fc400fe2007f6 */
/*0068*/                   IADD32I R0, -R0, 0x1f;                /* 0x1d00000001f70000 */
/*0070*/                   SEL R6, RZ, 0x1, !P0;                 /* 0x38a004000017ff06 */
/*0078*/                   MOV32I R2, 0x0;                       /* 0x010000000007f002 */
                                                                 /* 0x0003c400fe4007e4 */
/*0088*/                   MOV32I R3, 0x0;                       /* 0x010000000007f003 */
/*0090*/                   SHF.R.W R0, R5, R0, R6;               /* 0x5cfc030000070500 */
/*0098*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                       /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
                                                                 /* 0x001f8000ffe007ff */
/*00a8*/                   EXIT;                                 /* 0xe30000000007000f */
/*00b0*/                   BRA 0xb0;                             /* 0xe2400fffff87000f */
/*00b8*/                   NOP;                                  /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
```

Comment: Oh, this is awesome! I completely forgot about "funnel shift", since when I had noticed it before I didn't have anything interesting to do with it. Could you possibly link to other noteworthy uses of it?

Comment: The same strategy can also be extended to 64 bits. Seems to require different code paths for shifts <=32 bit and > 32 bits though.

Comment: @tera what's your strategy? I'm not really seeing a nice way to extend it

Comment: Just use two funnel shifts (one for the hi word, one for the lo word). The two code paths then come from the fact that `__funnelshift_r()` limits the shift to <=31 bits.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't have any links, the only uses of funnelshift I know of are rotations and big-int shifting (which this is an instance of, and so is using it to manipulate bit-streams). I'm across the road from you btw, at UvA.

Comment: How about we chat in real life then? My profile is linked to my GitHub profile so you can pretty easily figure out my name and email...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an adaptation of [a well-performing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431938/1593077) for the CPU:

```
template <typename T>
__device__ T div_by_power_of_2_rounding_up(T dividend, T divisor)
{
    auto log_2_of_divisor = lg(divisor);
    auto mask = divisor - 1;
    auto correction_for_rounding_up = ((dividend & mask) + mask) >> log_2_of_divisor;

    return (dividend >> log_2_of_divisor) + correction_for_rounding_up;
}
```

I wonder whether one can do much better.

The SASS code (using @RobertCrovella's test kernel) for SM_61 is:

```
code for sm_61
        Function : test(unsigned int, unsigned int)
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM61 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM61)"
                                                           /* 0x001fd400fe2007f6 */
/*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];           /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
/*0010*/                   IADD R0, RZ, -c[0x0][0x144];    /* 0x4c1100000517ff00 */
/*0018*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x144];          /* 0x4c98078005170002 */
                                                           /* 0x003fc40007a007f2 */
/*0028*/                   LOP.AND R0, R0, c[0x0][0x144];  /* 0x4c47000005170000 */
/*0030*/                   FLO.U32 R3, R0;                 /* 0x5c30000000070003 */
/*0038*/                   IADD32I R0, R2, -0x1;           /* 0x1c0ffffffff70200 */
                                                           /* 0x001fc400fcc017f5 */
/*0048*/                   IADD32I R3, -R3, 0x1f;          /* 0x1d00000001f70303 */
/*0050*/                   LOP.AND R2, R0, c[0x0][0x140];  /* 0x4c47000005070002 */
/*0058*/                   IADD R2, R0, R2;                /* 0x5c10000000270002 */
                                                           /* 0x001fd000fe2007f1 */
/*0068*/                   IADD32I R0, -R3, 0x1f;          /* 0x1d00000001f70300 */
/*0070*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x140];          /* 0x4c98078005070003 */
/*0078*/                   MOV32I R6, 0x0;                 /* 0x010000000007f006 */
                                                           /* 0x001fc400fc2407f1 */
/*0088*/                   SHR.U32 R4, R2, R0.reuse;       /* 0x5c28000000070204 */
/*0090*/                   SHR.U32 R5, R3, R0;             /* 0x5c28000000070305 */
/*0098*/                   MOV R2, R6;                     /* 0x5c98078000670002 */
                                                           /* 0x0003c400fe4007f4 */
/*00a8*/                   MOV32I R3, 0x0;                 /* 0x010000000007f003 */
/*00b0*/                   IADD R0, R4, R5;                /* 0x5c10000000570400 */
/*00b8*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                 /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
                                                           /* 0x001f8000ffe007ff */
/*00c8*/                   EXIT;                           /* 0xe30000000007000f */
/*00d0*/                   BRA 0xd0;                       /* 0xe2400fffff87000f */
/*00d8*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                                                           /* 0x001f8000fc0007e0 */
/*00e8*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
/*00f0*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
/*00f8*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
```

with `FLO` being the "find leading 1" instruction (thanks @tera). Anyway, those are lots of instructions, even if you ignore the loads from (what looks like) constant memory... the CPU function inspiring this one [compiles into](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZTUAHAvVAOwGdK0AbVAV2J4OmAIIcAtiADkABmmk0Exnh6YA8mwDCCAIZtgmGfICUpDgOLIj0gPS2A1AEktWkA4C0AD2Sf1AZgdPLwAJdQBlABVPDgJ0AFJ/ABFgNn5aWk8AdV0eHmzMLwJiXU8AMzZUDwA3TGIAI1QRD11JeNlRds6AJn88NmQefiwHRK1Y9EbUHgA6BETsLvje/sHhzFH/LS8ADgA2fuL%2BuYWuggBPRkwsMod%2BTjxU64c%2BAwdIxIAhJY77BwQCARGCB7LFdMgANaoWrEMp8ADuMyUtgAjvxMLFWJxbAAWWQ4nEAdloAE4AKy2ZD6Dx4DwIQ4eAgITAeJgsCR4ABedQ89XOHmAeGq/WAjOZHhKBhZqDKLTYNLYBEwhmISxWtxu/WuEAA%2BjqAOIAOQAqlo9SZRt09ss9g4wGBNWxtXqnIbItgADI6rTqACyAAUnB7sAAlExq/yOjatDj8CSYCBeC3oVDxQmfPBlCD2xMmC16%2Br8VQsNg6%2B7ETDgvT1NQQcP%2Bb6EpLw%2Bm12ThjrLfyYHgiCNRhwxuMJpMOCDVVB4dAmXMOP6YvIOTDVXL8XRKhyEBzsaykBxlEgODhTjaYMplTDIAgcTdsBxUkSDtjndgbYS3jj6U%2BVfjABAOIgHEYfgCCfc4PxPJ9Bw4WN4zrCNMDYfAyh%2BUQ/jQe5QOKXRVBFBxuWIJpNiSF5UGAbp90PRhUHhOobxlBxuhmLpQQIdc8F8LogmiHhgAgaJdAtNNPgcCsCEEO8CyLHgSx1K9OTyCBBK%2BUYmxY2wwRYXx%2Bh4LUuh44A5J4Tl%2BIcUdhK46DYJHe1EiSdsvksoc4MTS1bW8ITkjssz6xEudHC8Tcb1KajaOIbdbm6SyxIkhw9n8Y1PDHSITCk4t%2BiMhTc0czs1M7DpomsVQdXwaodX0dAJFaCFTMYPdohRIT00s7iHCqjgIWIzx%2BJnRhbOSByGyCP53SiZZPnCbBIlccbDWwfVLPsaJ2s67yPB6iBGE2bAx0YDxaDzFThscLJCH/JkNjQJDCCxBx6nBCF4V0Yh0A4PctADcbwk%2BETdDKJVwuDUQZiCLR9DAaRQJETAJAA1AHEMLC9FA%2BEzoA5l7xICsr0x66WHYZiOn8942uqrrNrsuz202AAxBxZAcdwev2lSRuwMbugmqaZs5uaFqJoISY2bzeIgRqctEQWScqNgCNQHUK1jGTyc2/bPMWfwdswITOYcWgJdsAAqKXM11HVC3S0srrBRUdUYTa81U74BalmLiDvCmvIGzy6YZ9wZblhWMX4GSJaltMSJ7R8LJdhxDdsFrRMwcT3YcAO6nlxWQ9Am1SY6g3HEFiOljy0RCswYrSvKpCVp1dPCPt6I6pJxqnacmDh02/r7N8xbbEYOzaF6HEyT2Qkw6TlO7yKngSqFavKuqza93FhsS6SVCjfvcHIYR5OEdQDBoNhspCNhplhD3JQVDUYgb3hdgIdA%2BpJWQf92AcLQ6b%2BgH0Y2WN6j6XvBXWeVcX76DfjqdgclnrEHOKZdA9UHCtxjpLKyncUTd0Gs7NB0R0A6g5GkDgmRvIJDXgLU2HgPD4MIfwYh20HDTkTm7O8sgJ7RGFskF4fFV4iT%2BMAZAvgDzEERjeJk65NygVyBWXQ6BwJeBIM8SsgV6hnkUX/O6r8EB7gqow1AGJJGDmADhO8gEX6Vk6hdRhmBGAg0oKDHg%2BhgB6IxGwJ%2B/xdC1HRu%2BRghEaww0JmglhY4IA0P6HQg620FhLh1iJfW5DOhNiCPHVC5dK7z1aBIcq6BkAIKQSg5qAsOFdVFrw4mAjfApgMagTqqMmTeLekeeGhRqKPi3IBLQk1LLREVhPTJEApbHS0KgZQqgNh1P/B4dqEg7LrgIFfRxbw341OqaYjGhwewOBhMeD%2BDEL732ZHeUoyxujABObjWIJRDiUXCm%2BG8dDrh7mAoCPCW5%2BhtRhiQc4gTBmWm6AAqWAASegloyTxDJJ8BIZISKWkCD0PY0QODnEVLoLw4KtBsHRQQE5icggnNkb4QWgLZB7mWGCiFUKN5kgxVi85x1GGJDpugfajN6YgwcOEZON4v52R5bHPF3R/kIGIIFAV5LPiYHBUkUl3RxWUpleK3p0L0WYupdiwVuK/kcHqPUIF%2B0FXgs%2BEqkiXZELoFvLpJ0KraWCuJuNcam4NQOCejeGWHg5aJ3cIaylOLOY2lVIK0JZhRgQuNTi5IAbugQEVh2NBQQvUQslcqwVkaIDa0Tr3AWfxDzgIGO/O8X89z9FiJWc1DERCMGeuuDYSpYiiXwKQF6eBorJ1ir0hJxdfiOGvmMsR8Nr5qCVDwcCCAsZ4H8ZjLATyQIlmcVYuEuhgA3kOPDDZKok5LrusnWiiFtyMA4IEtJoCMk5LyS3JqODWqcJIqUzNaD7jHieOa14ziX2MIkPEvyfwH2PCdOavUhw9g4ksj%2Bp9949DhS/l1bJOTYHnDLEBiAJLGF7n1W5SqB0J5Qe8jBqkxA4EIZxBAQt9M9wYZlXsDDd7WocHpP9Z4pCP1RM1kuCeOoAGNHwzRQjxGaZ7lo5mJUiDPAgptFRiewSMMS07Z0fKZdgHpLKtCOocIaK1XyReltU9drjRRGrZjO1b3SdLupDxSE1DOpKIwFQbw6F4T5WhQuIgCCVPyLo2jL0PxKlkRFI8wrMYh3NQ/YgtSew8D3IWKGwrzVkDIIMIKDgcS%2BEcUqAY4ElJIUS3cJgHBY1/FEqgNiSoPATI8HhuBCXKigVHfh8dFnhEBcVIPCLIE/53lon5kVNyNGK1AnsjGAn/qmeCxCG8DWUSnGSN0PcZQcK9m6xN5ItBAl/HCAAaQ9C8dc7g9MLEVuTIG41RBJA3pzEMWgQxpi0JEAAWloN0X1jSfFiRykIIYAAa5NgOEi0DiF7JCuFgq7b8qWzK9sGO8sd07nxzuXc5uEN7727JJaATPOeZVMkK2QMQdT5625FKXExkWPCLQeD1nuZBROuEoiSiC9tl7j4DMGfYYZoyLMTM8NM2ZgIFlOPAys%2Biay3yKk2ds26/X3wtl3ccwVZzbXW2wtchrdy7giGE882dhj3nxgkF8n5gz8XoHNUXWVhqUQfqlQaiFA9oUCrhTaRFyK2JoupaqrQ6qor8r%2BVYcKRLROm%2Bt1K61aq6V/G6Ml6taW9yBH4DlzVJyPOitBYamG%2BtoVW8%2BDb6VyfQ0YilbCs1Fq9Ku5tZ7uNrLDVZ99d8K0qbGDBsNWGjVEaTnRoxLGqWCbPjm7T6d7odRW894b4mi3ybuiptTx3wW1Hia5ABmwdiXjxEoxIKN51aNFtJFoO4FcQhdD%2BLKwIRUolsdPnNRdO8K11/1L0/QPud1Ws%2B9EoofI74dgR9S8gcCH91sei022vPDtEzAqBTY9MqIeHYXHBqTTAWZyBMTBMAKmGfUDP9JcEpEnPpDuOCThLQbyeKGfPUIsRUCAnUUCRgCArqAeBJIIQgw4EgsglEAhcJehbycg7oHYS0ESMWNWCeRgRg2hFgq0byKAM2IgggegkwSJMYMYOKMkUnPWCeYWIQrheKVmRwKpDgNxXeZkHgLaHtW%2BI8CEPALaUaDhG0IDTwaJD6dQAANX/1Tk2n4OYKkM1miUlSAI3jkz%2BFzTfgMUAjwGUDUHjGPysXn2enOFIGG3pDfgS3BHElyGHQPiPkzAZQGgSxkTyHAhKArBW0cGwB8DC0QikUkH3DPgRkEUpEWWAEPVAPRzkmFWEBTCNzPWgPx3L2KWJzFhnyCEk1phCWZRcI1i1n%2B1ZTYQ8NMx8IQDUBghBmAEPiCzRgV30FAmE133ODwklWBw5zWLwmExfTqC20/3AnETvCoDoSkXvF12qEHCRm/ASBALRyrllVkFoBaOQRgPaLQM6N4WYVbQcNCSSntHtGnAMxiU4LtCBLIRwRk03kcEmOmI4FRxATqIeWIF6CgPeLaKvS8GoidGP2%2BJn2WjJm8hpzJ0/VMylmuNKhPHsI9i2kmy1hxNfEVBexEPpKtDzghBexWnVjcKZLxIIDvRk28K0QRL3AxBEEVDwASOOIG10HjGgnA34C8AhmXTvAsEEGsDP2PhYkNiAWpKwDLBEDRP8B1F32lMVAxIKQZw4X5KKPQK6PYU5K6lJIUOoMnlik2lBJaWZMFPBKgHZNtB5IhO8mwXXjjgTi8LhNFIlP1KFBPB1FEHqOVKtI%2BKCCmHyEInuHwX4HpK4UDLHFvxn2CS9IZO4S6JeyzKQjLCoOhOAMcyPARHcGQCuO63PBvFUSpAeUMT0D7TM3QAsysSoPsm3kfA4CuGQGlMyNM10T4GvF81rRzl1mc0EUHHo3CmXxqINMwHqKEA4HU1aNQRNizE3yQM1TShkgynLErDfn31rG6NvFAl0LsgvNknbMUnrwniCGuR4E31fIynkkUh%2BNjnsBLKoKGN/PDE5ggGfK2Bgom05kwyEKtF0IfLAoZMgv9Jgr2kwzgsgptBtFQuM08Nk1IqROKkfT/TqIAEV0RMR2AtA3jrTukviuEjN3S/hZtVAxtDwyEN40ipc7xoh3wUDrhaT%2BjadeSWNtZwTyTcoSL1IuwBwyh7hkAywkI6hSCMQVj4zDSky35lT%2BwzwtR9xVL1KsBiAtK61HiMka5qogFFzzZCsEBd8IAFcSZDZeshAcZm53LohPLtLvLQJmKBY8ySJ/zSw4DypdIn1l4HB/BugZ8accNzZpJZIorchf1tQURo9EqnSiA2J8hQyJ5hEIBrlm0BoVIKqtBaBZBuhgMhp7VOY8A0zBYCrchODvIVKBhzLNLFyKYIVm109kFDUhqkgZ8ZMei/jTFCtchiLUkAJtK5J2BYgUQ3KVrQJ/KvKOIyCr4Nq8cjygJoNUrLZyosCdzMrYrm4ErCS4ZCquoxiGdSryqqYqqxhar6qVImqMxWqgh2qiq/UuFuq1Lsy%2BrtKBqMxLd3iJ5JqPTU5/r5qOhpAzAeAZAyQFA2AZBaAFBUAZBcC/VlzLAtSuxsbSACBjBkazAIQQB/BZAZhaAyQSR/BCQcRaAcQ9gyR/AGbZAyRSBUbpAcQMaKaGAZAFAuASVya5BkbSA4BYAkB9C6hyBuARkb46gQBgAyQ8RSAyhiw6JKB6hhalBgiCBNBh1hb8BsYWBaguApbyARd%2BbTAGBmAsQbbvBfAPAAhOdno347JezaJFwva2hkg5kYg4g7JUh0hMgPAchFxo7ChsJyhKgag6hGhmhMlpb%2Bb0bSBMbbbcbpASbr9/xdg9gPALCKkHAyQZhBayaKa8xSBqbegq6dhaA9huhyQ2aSQdhug6q%2BaZBq6c75ARbpAxaQAJba6ZaYBEAUAVaxkyAKB1q2c1bBgnF/ASQSUdaZI9aIADbbajaijTbzhza8BLahQMRhaNkHbpa2QXaZA3a/BAgplvb5hkg/awsggPAJhw60gMhsgEiCgigShE6qgYRU6WR06Ua0ahbc6ZAC6Odi7S6cR7wqj4qZgSQZhB7JbTAqaQBuhlscRcGSQ9gu6ObaBmayQrRe6BaFApBaqSUB6cbRbzBR6a6pazBZap6Fa57lbF7iAQAOJkBaBCRtbda759bDaRljaD6j6T7rbz77bx7r6Vrb6fB76varBn6khX7Y7QgIhohA6Zlg7ARQ6%2BKI6f7o6/646AHSgPAKhgGU6mgwHJAM7IHs7ha87YG0Z4GLD%2BG9ZCQFBMHKb66cGcRUHma6qdhZBCR/B/AcQdhyRKH%2B63HGHxaWGsHKHugoHB687/Ha6zAxd2AQAcQgA%3D%3D%3D) just:

```
    tzcnt   rax, rsi
    lea     rcx, [rdi - 1]
    shrx    rax, rcx, rax
    add     rax, 1
    test    rdi, rdi
    cmove   rax, rdi
```

(with clang 3.9.0).

Comment: `FLO.U32` -> Find Leading One.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T> __device__ T div_by_power_of_2_rounding_up(T p, T q)
{
    return p==0 ? 0 : ((p - 1) >> lg(q)) + 1;
}
```

One instruction shorter than [Robert's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43565124/1662425) (but see his [comeback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566362/1662425)) if my count is correct, or the same instruction count as the funnel shift. Has a branch though - not sure if that makes a difference (other than a benefit if the entire warp gets zero `p` inputs):

```
Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

    code for sm_61
        Function : _Z4testjj
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM61 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM61)"
                                                                                         /* 0x001fc000fda007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];                                 /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/                   ISETP.EQ.AND P0, PT, RZ, c[0x0][0x140], PT;           /* 0x4b6503800507ff07 */
        /*0018*/         {         MOV R0, RZ;                                           /* 0x5c9807800ff70000 */
        /*0028*/               @P0 BRA 0x90;        }                                    /* 0x001fc800fec007fd */
                                                                                         /* 0xe24000000600000f */
        /*0030*/                   IADD R0, RZ, -c[0x0][0x144];                          /* 0x4c1100000517ff00 */
        /*0038*/                   LOP.AND R0, R0, c[0x0][0x144];                        /* 0x4c47000005170000 */
                                                                                         /* 0x003fc400ffa00711 */
        /*0048*/                   FLO.U32 R0, R0;                                       /* 0x5c30000000070000 */
        /*0050*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x140];                                /* 0x4c98078005070003 */
        /*0058*/                   IADD32I R2, -R0, 0x1f;                                /* 0x1d00000001f70002 */
                                                                                         /* 0x001fd800fcc007f5 */
        /*0068*/                   IADD32I R0, R3, -0x1;                                 /* 0x1c0ffffffff70300 */
        /*0070*/                   IADD32I R2, -R2, 0x1f;                                /* 0x1d00000001f70202 */
        /*0078*/                   SHR.U32 R0, R0, R2;                                   /* 0x5c28000000270000 */
                                                                                         /* 0x001fc800fe2007f6 */
        /*0088*/                   IADD32I R0, R0, 0x1;                                  /* 0x1c00000000170000 */
        /*0090*/                   MOV32I R2, 0x0;                                       /* 0x010000000007f002 */
        /*0098*/                   MOV32I R3, 0x0;                                       /* 0x010000000007f003 */
                                                                                         /* 0x001ffc00ffe000f1 */
        /*00a8*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                                       /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
        /*00b0*/                   EXIT;                                                 /* 0xe30000000007000f */
        /*00b8*/                   BRA 0xb8;                                             /* 0xe2400fffff87000f */
        ..........................
```

I believe it should still be possible to shave an instruction or two from the funnel shift by writing it in PTX (**Morning update**: as [Robert has proven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566362/1662425) in the meantime), but I really need to go to bed.

**Update2**: Doing that (using [Harold's funnel shift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43564921/1662425) and writing the function in PTX)

```
_device__ uint32_t div_by_power_of_2_rounding_up(uint32_t p, uint32_t q)
{
  uint32_t ret;
  asm volatile("{\r\t"
               ".reg.u32        shift, mask, lo, hi;\n\t"
               "bfind.u32       shift, %2;\r\t"
               "sub.u32         mask, %2, 1;\r\t"
               "add.cc.u32      lo, %1, mask;\r\t"
               "addc.u32        hi, 0, 0;\r\t"
               "shf.r.wrap.b32  %0, lo, hi, shift;\n\t"
               "}"
                : "=r"(ret) : "r"(p), "r"(q));
  return ret;
}
```

just gets us to the same instruction count as Robert has already achieved with his simpler C code:

```
Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

    code for sm_61
        Function : _Z4testjj
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM61 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM61)"
                                                                            /* 0x001fc000fec007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];                    /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/                   MOV R0, c[0x0][0x144];                   /* 0x4c98078005170000 */
        /*0018*/         {         IADD32I R2, R0, -0x1;                    /* 0x1c0ffffffff70002 */
        /*0028*/                   FLO.U32 R0, c[0x0][0x144];        }      /* 0x001fc400fec00716 */
                                                                            /* 0x4c30000005170000 */
        /*0030*/                   IADD R5.CC, R2, c[0x0][0x140];           /* 0x4c10800005070205 */
        /*0038*/                   IADD.X R6, RZ, RZ;                       /* 0x5c1008000ff7ff06 */
                                                                            /* 0x003fc800fc8007f1 */
        /*0048*/                   MOV32I R2, 0x0;                          /* 0x010000000007f002 */
        /*0050*/                   MOV32I R3, 0x0;                          /* 0x010000000007f003 */
        /*0058*/                   SHF.R.W R0, R5, R0, R6;                  /* 0x5cfc030000070500 */
                                                                            /* 0x001ffc00ffe000f1 */
        /*0068*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                          /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
        /*0070*/                   EXIT;                                    /* 0xe30000000007000f */
        /*0078*/                   BRA 0x78;                                /* 0xe2400fffff87000f */
        ..........................
```

Answer (score 2):

riffing off of [the kewl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566200/1695960) by @tera:

```
 template <typename T> __device__ T pdqru(T p, T q)
{
    return bool(p) * (((p - 1) >> lg(q)) + 1);
}
```

11 instructions (no branches, no predication) to get the result in R0:

```
Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_61
                Function : _Z4testjj
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM61 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM61)"
                                                                   /* 0x001fc800fec007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];           /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/                   IADD R0, RZ, -c[0x0][0x144];    /* 0x4c1100000517ff00 */
        /*0018*/                   LOP.AND R0, R0, c[0x0][0x144];  /* 0x4c47000005170000 */
                                                                   /* 0x003fc400ffa00711 */
        /*0028*/                   FLO.U32 R0, R0;                 /* 0x5c30000000070000 */
        /*0030*/                   MOV R5, c[0x0][0x140];          /* 0x4c98078005070005 */
        /*0038*/                   IADD32I R2, -R0, 0x1f;          /* 0x1d00000001f70002 */
                                                                   /* 0x001fd800fcc007f5 */
        /*0048*/                   IADD32I R0, R5, -0x1;           /* 0x1c0ffffffff70500 */
        /*0050*/                   IADD32I R2, -R2, 0x1f;          /* 0x1d00000001f70202 */
        /*0058*/                   SHR.U32 R0, R0, R2;             /* 0x5c28000000270000 */
                                                                   /* 0x001fd000fe2007f1 */
        /*0068*/                   IADD32I R0, R0, 0x1;            /* 0x1c00000000170000 */
        /*0070*/                   MOV32I R2, 0x0;                 /* 0x010000000007f002 */
        /*0078*/                   MOV32I R3, 0x0;                 /* 0x010000000007f003 */
                                                                   /* 0x001ffc001e2007f2 */
        /*0088*/                   ICMP.NE R0, R0, RZ, R5;         /* 0x5b4b02800ff70000 */
        /*0090*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                 /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
        /*0098*/                   EXIT;                           /* 0xe30000000007000f */
                                                                   /* 0x001f8000fc0007ff */
        /*00a8*/                   BRA 0xa0;                       /* 0xe2400fffff07000f */
        /*00b0*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*00b8*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                ..........................
```

After studying the above SASS code, it seemed evident that these two instructions:

```
        /*0038*/                   IADD32I R2, -R0, 0x1f;          /* 0x1d00000001f70002 */
                                                                   /* 0x001fd800fcc007f5 */
        ...
        /*0050*/                   IADD32I R2, -R2, 0x1f;          /* 0x1d00000001f70202 */
```

shouldn't really be necessary.  I don't have a precise explanation, but my assumption is that because the `FLO.U32` SASS instruction does not have precisely the same semantics as the `__ffs()` intrinsic, the compiler apparently has an idiom when using that intrinsic, which wraps the basic `FLO` instruction that is doing the work.  It wasn't obvious how to work around this at the C++ source code level, but I was able to use the `bfind` [PTX instruction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#integer-arithmetic-instructions-bfind) in a way to reduce the instruction count further, to 7 according to my count (to get the answer into a register):

```
$ cat t107.cu
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
__device__ unsigned r = 0;


static __device__ __inline__ uint32_t __my_bfind(uint32_t val){
  uint32_t ret;
  asm volatile("bfind.u32 %0, %1;" : "=r"(ret): "r"(val));
  return ret;}

template <typename T> __device__ T pdqru(T p, T q)
{
    return bool(p) * (((p - 1) >> (__my_bfind(q))) + 1);
}

__global__ void test(unsigned p, unsigned q){
#ifdef USE_DISPLAY
  unsigned q2 = 16;
  unsigned z = 0;
  unsigned l = 1U<<31;
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, q, pdqru(p, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, q2, pdqru(p, q2));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, z, pdqru(p, z));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", z, q, pdqru(z, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", l, q, pdqru(l, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", q, l, pdqru(q, l));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", l, l, pdqru(l, l));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", q, q, pdqru(q, q));
#else
  r = pdqru(p, q);
#endif
}


int main(){
  unsigned h_r;
  test<<<1,1>>>(32767, 32);
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_r, r, sizeof(unsigned));
  printf("result = %u\n", h_r);
}


$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t107 t107.cu -std=c++11
$ cuobjdump -sass t107

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_61

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_61
                Function : _Z4testjj
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM61 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM61)"
                                                                        /* 0x001c4400fe0007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];                /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/         {         MOV32I R3, 0x0;                      /* 0x010000000007f003 */
        /*0018*/                   FLO.U32 R2, c[0x0][0x144];        }  /* 0x4c30000005170002 */
                                                                        /* 0x003fd800fec007f6 */
        /*0028*/                   MOV R5, c[0x0][0x140];               /* 0x4c98078005070005 */
        /*0030*/                   IADD32I R0, R5, -0x1;                /* 0x1c0ffffffff70500 */
        /*0038*/                   SHR.U32 R0, R0, R2;                  /* 0x5c28000000270000 */
                                                                        /* 0x001fc800fca007f1 */
        /*0048*/                   IADD32I R0, R0, 0x1;                 /* 0x1c00000000170000 */
        /*0050*/                   MOV32I R2, 0x0;                      /* 0x010000000007f002 */
        /*0058*/                   ICMP.NE R0, R0, RZ, R5;              /* 0x5b4b02800ff70000 */
                                                                        /* 0x001ffc00ffe000f1 */
        /*0068*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                      /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
        /*0070*/                   EXIT;                                /* 0xe30000000007000f */
        /*0078*/                   BRA 0x78;                            /* 0xe2400fffff87000f */
                ..........................



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [5,0]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t107 t107.cu -std=c++11 -DUSE_DISPLAY
$ cuda-memcheck ./t107
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
result 32767/32 = 1024
result 32767/16 = 2048
result 32767/0 = 1
result 0/32 = 0
result 2147483648/32 = 67108864
result 32/2147483648 = 1
result 2147483648/2147483648 = 1
result 32/32 = 1
result = 0
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I've only demonstrated the 32-bit example, above.

I think I could make the case that there are really only 6 instructions doing the "work" in the above kernel SASS, and that the remainder of the instructions are kernel "overhead" and/or the instructions needed to store the register result into global memory.  It seems evident that the compiler is generating just these instructions as a result of the function:

```
        /*0018*/                   FLO.U32 R2, c[0x0][0x144];  // find bit set in q
                                                                        /*  */
        /*0028*/                   MOV R5, c[0x0][0x140];      // load p
        /*0030*/                   IADD32I R0, R5, -0x1;       // subtract 1 from p
        /*0038*/                   SHR.U32 R0, R0, R2;         // shift p right by q bit
                                                                        /*  */
        /*0048*/                   IADD32I R0, R0, 0x1;        // add 1 to result
        /*0050*/                   ...                                  /*  */
        /*0058*/                   ICMP.NE R0, R0, RZ, R5;     // account for p=0 case
```

However this would be inconsistent with the way I've counted other cases (they should all probably be reduced by 1).

Comment: `FLO` isn't supposed to have the same semantics as `__ffs`: `__ffs` counts _trailing_ zeros, not _leading_ zeros; you probably meant `__clz`... in the PTX (for my version) we actually have the equivalent of `clz(q & ~p)` which is weird in itself.

Comment: I didn't say anywhere that FLO is supposed to have the same semantics as `__ffs` and I said my assumption was they were different.  `FLO` is find leading one, and I was looking for the PTX instruction that would do that, and it appeared to be `bfind`.   I assumed that the reason that the `__ffs()`  was incorporating additional unneeded instructions was that it was due to the difference in semantics between `FLO` and `__ffs()`.  The compiler doesn't seem to strip out the unneeded instructions, even though they seem unnecessary, and I haven't determined the exact reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

One possible straightforward approach:

```
$ cat t105.cu
#include <cstdio>

__device__ unsigned r = 0;

template <typename T>
__device__ T pdqru(T p, T q){

  T p1 = p +  (q-1);
  if (sizeof(T) == 8)
    q = __ffsll(q);
  else
    q = __ffs(q);
  return (p1<p)?((p>>(q-1))+1) :(p1 >> (q-1));
}

__global__ void test(unsigned p, unsigned q){
#ifdef USE_DISPLAY
  unsigned q2 = 16;
  unsigned z = 0;
  unsigned l = 1U<<31;
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, q, pdqru(p, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, q2, pdqru(p, q2));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, z, pdqru(p, z));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", z, q, pdqru(z, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", l, q, pdqru(l, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", q, l, pdqru(q, l));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", l, l, pdqru(l, l));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", q, q, pdqru(q, q));
#else
  r = pdqru(p, q);
#endif
}


int main(){
  unsigned h_r;
  test<<<1,1>>>(32767, 32);
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_r, r, sizeof(unsigned));
  printf("result = %u\n", h_r);
}


$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t105 t105.cu
$ cuobjdump -sass ./t105

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_61

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_61
                Function : _Z4testjj
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM61 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM61)"
                                                                         /* 0x001fc800fec007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];                 /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/                   IADD R0, RZ, -c[0x0][0x144];          /* 0x4c1100000517ff00 */
        /*0018*/                   LOP.AND R0, R0, c[0x0][0x144];        /* 0x4c47000005170000 */
                                                                         /* 0x005fd401fe20003d */
        /*0028*/                   FLO.U32 R2, R0;                       /* 0x5c30000000070002 */
        /*0030*/                   MOV R0, c[0x0][0x144];                /* 0x4c98078005170000 */
        /*0038*/                   IADD32I R3, -R2, 0x1f;                /* 0x1d00000001f70203 */
                                                                         /* 0x001fd000fc2007f1 */
        /*0048*/                   IADD32I R0, R0, -0x1;                 /* 0x1c0ffffffff70000 */
        /*0050*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140];                /* 0x4c98078005070002 */
        /*0058*/                   IADD32I R4, -R3, 0x1f;                /* 0x1d00000001f70304 */
                                                                         /* 0x001fd800fe2007f6 */
        /*0068*/                   IADD R5, R0, c[0x0][0x140];           /* 0x4c10000005070005 */
        /*0070*/                   ISETP.LT.U32.AND P0, PT, R5, R0, PT;  /* 0x5b62038000070507 */
        /*0078*/                   SHR.U32 R0, R2, R4;                   /* 0x5c28000000470200 */
                                                                         /* 0x001fd000fc2007f1 */
        /*0088*/                   IADD32I R0, R0, 0x1;                  /* 0x1c00000000170000 */
        /*0090*/                   MOV32I R2, 0x0;                       /* 0x010000000007f002 */
        /*0098*/                   MOV32I R3, 0x0;                       /* 0x010000000007f003 */
                                                                         /* 0x001ffc001e2007f2 */
        /*00a8*/              @!P0 SHR.U32 R0, R5, R4;                   /* 0x5c28000000480500 */
        /*00b0*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                       /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
        /*00b8*/                   EXIT;                                 /* 0xe30000000007000f */
                                                                         /* 0x001f8000fc0007ff */
        /*00c8*/                   BRA 0xc0;                             /* 0xe2400fffff07000f */
        /*00d0*/                   NOP;                                  /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*00d8*/                   NOP;                                  /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                                                                         /* 0x001f8000fc0007e0 */
        /*00e8*/                   NOP;                                  /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*00f0*/                   NOP;                                  /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*00f8*/                   NOP;                                  /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                ..........................



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [5,0]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t105 t105.cu -DUSE_DISPLAY
$ cuda-memcheck ./t105
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
result 32767/32 = 1024
result 32767/16 = 2048
result 32767/0 = 2048
result 0/32 = 0
result 2147483648/32 = 67108864
result 32/2147483648 = 1
result 2147483648/2147483648 = 1
result 32/32 = 1
result = 0
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Approximately 14 SASS instructions for the 32-bit case, to get the answer into R0.  It produces spurious results for the divide-by-zero case.

The equivalent assembly for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43564755/1695960) case looks like this:

```
$ cat t106.cu
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
__device__ unsigned r = 0;


template <typename T> __device__ int find_first_set(T x);
template <> __device__ int find_first_set<uint32_t>(uint32_t x) { return __ffs(x);   }
template <> __device__ int find_first_set<uint64_t>(uint64_t x) { return __ffsll(x); }

template <typename T>  __device__ T lg(T x) { return find_first_set(x) - 1; }

template <typename T>
__device__ T pdqru(T dividend, T divisor)
{
    auto log_2_of_divisor = lg(divisor);
    auto mask = divisor - 1;
    auto correction_for_rounding_up = ((dividend & mask) + mask) >> log_2_of_divisor;

    return (dividend >> log_2_of_divisor) + correction_for_rounding_up;
}

__global__ void test(unsigned p, unsigned q){
#ifdef USE_DISPLAY
  unsigned q2 = 16;
  unsigned z = 0;
  unsigned l = 1U<<31;
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, q, pdqru(p, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, q2, pdqru(p, q2));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", p, z, pdqru(p, z));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", z, q, pdqru(z, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", l, q, pdqru(l, q));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", q, l, pdqru(q, l));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", l, l, pdqru(l, l));
  printf("result %u/%u = %u\n", q, q, pdqru(q, q));
#else
  r = pdqru(p, q);
#endif
}


int main(){
  unsigned h_r;
  test<<<1,1>>>(32767, 32);
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_r, r, sizeof(unsigned));
  printf("result = %u\n", h_r);
}


$ nvcc -std=c++11  -arch=sm_61 -o t106 t106.cu
$ cuobjdump -sass t106

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_61

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

        code for sm_61
                Function : _Z4testjj
        .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM61 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM61)"
                                                                   /* 0x001fd400fe2007f6 */
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];           /* 0x4c98078000870001 */
        /*0010*/                   IADD R0, RZ, -c[0x0][0x144];    /* 0x4c1100000517ff00 */
        /*0018*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x144];          /* 0x4c98078005170002 */
                                                                   /* 0x003fc40007a007f2 */
        /*0028*/                   LOP.AND R0, R0, c[0x0][0x144];  /* 0x4c47000005170000 */
        /*0030*/                   FLO.U32 R3, R0;                 /* 0x5c30000000070003 */
        /*0038*/                   IADD32I R0, R2, -0x1;           /* 0x1c0ffffffff70200 */
                                                                   /* 0x001fc400fcc017f5 */
        /*0048*/                   IADD32I R3, -R3, 0x1f;          /* 0x1d00000001f70303 */
        /*0050*/                   LOP.AND R2, R0, c[0x0][0x140];  /* 0x4c47000005070002 */
        /*0058*/                   IADD R2, R0, R2;                /* 0x5c10000000270002 */
                                                                   /* 0x001fd000fe2007f1 */
        /*0068*/                   IADD32I R0, -R3, 0x1f;          /* 0x1d00000001f70300 */
        /*0070*/                   MOV R3, c[0x0][0x140];          /* 0x4c98078005070003 */
        /*0078*/                   MOV32I R6, 0x0;                 /* 0x010000000007f006 */
                                                                   /* 0x001fc400fc2407f1 */
        /*0088*/                   SHR.U32 R4, R2, R0.reuse;       /* 0x5c28000000070204 */
        /*0090*/                   SHR.U32 R5, R3, R0;             /* 0x5c28000000070305 */
        /*0098*/                   MOV R2, R6;                     /* 0x5c98078000670002 */
                                                                   /* 0x0003c400fe4007f4 */
        /*00a8*/                   MOV32I R3, 0x0;                 /* 0x010000000007f003 */
        /*00b0*/                   IADD R0, R4, R5;                /* 0x5c10000000570400 */
        /*00b8*/                   STG.E [R2], R0;                 /* 0xeedc200000070200 */
                                                                   /* 0x001f8000ffe007ff */
        /*00c8*/                   EXIT;                           /* 0xe30000000007000f */
        /*00d0*/                   BRA 0xd0;                       /* 0xe2400fffff87000f */
        /*00d8*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                                                                   /* 0x001f8000fc0007e0 */
        /*00e8*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*00f0*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
        /*00f8*/                   NOP;                            /* 0x50b0000000070f00 */
                ..........................



Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [5,0]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
$
```

which appears to be 1 instruction longer, by my count.

Comment: It wasn't an along-the-way edit - it's the whole point of the question (and of the original question); since otherwise, indeed, the straightforward approach comes to mind relatively easily, and it doesn't seem like there could be overly interesting alternatives.

Comment: I've modified it to handle overflow.  It adds a few instructions.

Comment: The SASS instructions count for the 32 bit case is basically the same as your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution via population count. I tried the 32-bit variant only, testing it exhaustively against the reference implementation. Since the divisor `q` is a power of 2, we can trivially determine the shift count `s` with the help of the population count operation. The remainder `t` of the truncating division can be computed by simple mask `m` derived directly from the divisor `q`.

```
// For p in [0,0xffffffff], q = (1 << s) with s in [0,31], compute ceil(p/q)
__device__ uint32_t reference (uint32_t p, uint32_t q)
{
    uint32_t r = p / q;
    if ((q * r) < p) r++;
    return r;
}

// For p in [0,0xffffffff], q = (1 << s) with s in [0,31], compute ceil(p/q)
__device__ uint32_t solution (uint32_t p, uint32_t q)
{
    uint32_t r, s, t, m;
    m = q - 1;
    s = __popc (m);
    r = p >> s;
    t = p & m;
    if (t > 0) r++;
    return r;
}
```

Whether `solution()` is faster than the previously posted codes will likely depend on the specific GPU architecture. Using CUDA 8.0, it compiles to the following sequence of PTX instructions:

```
add.s32         %r3, %r2, -1;
popc.b32        %r4, %r3;
shr.u32         %r5, %r1, %r4;
and.b32         %r6, %r3, %r1;
setp.ne.s32     %p1, %r6, 0;
selp.u32        %r7, 1, 0, %p1;
add.s32         %r8, %r5, %r7;
```

For sm_5x, this translates into machine code pretty much 1:1, except that the two instructions `SETP` and `SELP` get contracted into a single `ICMP`, because the comparison is with 0.

Comment: I don't either... I only have a 5.2, which I'll probably use next week for some performance comparisons. but you could still post the PTX and/or the SASS, with Robert's kernel, so that we see what it looks like.

Comment: Oh, wait, you've essentially just replaced the `lg()` implementation, and other than that you're doing the more-straightforward version of the round-up-correction. Now that I think about it, maybe I should just replace the `lg()` with your popcnt-based code, It's almost certainly better.

Comment: @einpoklum I added the generated PTX code, per your suggestion.